# Run NUnit Test Assemblies in Parallel on Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, parallel-processing, nunit

We have project with many NUnit test, and it taken longer to run them, an our build process.  Our NUnit test are grouped together in different projects, that compile different assemblies (DLL files), we have about 10 projects full of NUnit tests, in our solution.

We decided to try and run our NUnit assemblies in parallel on our Team Foundation Server 2012, to try and speed up our test time. Note; assemblies in parallel and not each test in parallel, we still want our tests to run one after the other, in it's given assembly.

So how can we setup our Team Foundation Server to run our NUnit assemblies in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

If they are taking longer then they are likely Integration Tests and not Unit Tests, even if they are written in a unit testing framework.

You should do only unit tests (tests that need no instances of your application) at build time. Integration and UI tests should be executed at deployment time. As you deploy the same code to progressive quality environments (DEV->QA->UA->PROD) you can run more and more long running verification tests.

This will reduce your build time significantly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, we are looking for a quick win here.  That is why we trying to invest time to see if this can help.  We do need to look out our tests and we are aware of it.

Comment: I have setup RM with a pipeline for a customer in less than 2 hours. Sounds like a quick win to me....